# Average the sal then sort in descending order

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I want to list all the employees that make more than the average salary. I'm alittle lost on this one. I need to add up all the salary's then average them out and only display the ones that make more than the average. I need alot of help on this one.

My query that doesnt work

```
 SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, deptno from emp where sal avg(sal);
 select empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, deptno from emp where sal avg(sal)
                                                               *
 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
 SQL>
```

Table

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, deptno from emp;

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE         SAL     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT 17-NOV-81       5000         10
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   01-MAY-81       2850         30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER   09-JUN-81       2450         10
  7566 JONES      MANAGER   02-APR-81       2975         20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  28-SEP-81       1250         30
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20-FEB-81       1600         30
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  08-SEP-81       1500         30
  7900 JAMES      CLERK     03-DEC-81        950         30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN  22-FEB-81       1250         30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST   03-DEC-81       3000         20
  7369 SMITH      CLERK     17-DEC-80        800         20

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE         SAL     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------- ----------
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   09-DEC-82       3000         20
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK     12-JAN-83       1100         20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK     23-JAN-82       1300         10

 14 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the invalid relational operator error because you nave omitted the `less than` 
sign in your query.  Please learn to read [the documentation.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators002.htm#i1028549)

Beyond that, you need to write a sub-query to calculate the average salary.  So your query should look like this:

```
select empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, deptno 
from emp 
where sal > (select  avg(sal) from emp)
order by sal desc;
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't Oracle support [windowed functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10736/analysis.htm#i1006709)? I'm not sure whether you can use a windowed function directly in the WHERE clause, but at least you can derive a table from a query that uses it and then reference the corresponding column in a condition:

```
SELECT
  empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, deptno
FROM (
  SELECT
    empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal, deptno
    AVG(sal) OVER () AS avgsal
  FROM emp
) s
WHERE sal > avgsal
```